# How to upload PDF file in swift using form-data or any other method

Tags: swift, file-upload, form-data

can we upload pdf/doc file using form-data in swift. Or any other way to upload. if possible please provide working example as i am new in this technology.

Answer (score 3):

Its good to use excellent Alamofire library to upload any doc (such as pdf file).The below code will explain how to use alamofire to upload a file

```
Alamofire.upload(
        multipartFormData: {
            multipartFormData in

            if let urlString = urlBase2 {
                let pdfData = try! Data(contentsOf: urlString.asURL())
                var data : Data = pdfData

                multipartFormData.append(pdfData, withName: "pdfDocuments", fileName: namePDF, mimeType:"application/pdf")
                for (key, value) in body {
                    multipartFormData.append(((value as? String)?.data(using: .utf8))!, withName: key)
                }

                print("Multi part Content -Type")
                print(multipartFormData.contentType)
                print("Multi part FIN ")
                print("Multi part Content-Length")
                print(multipartFormData.contentLength)
                print("Multi part Content-Boundary")
                print(multipartFormData.boundary)
            }
    },
        to: url,
        method: .post,
        headers: header,
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in

            switch encodingResult {

            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    print(" responses ")
                    print(response)
                    print("Responses ended")

                    onCompletion(true, "Something went wrong", 200)

                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
                onCompletion(false, "Something went wrong", 200)
            }
    })
```

Comment: for (key, value) in body  //throwing an error ->Use of unresolved identyfier "body"

Comment: body is dictionary of parameters in case if you want to also send the parameter along with file

Comment: headers: header //what is this header parameter?

Comment: header describe request formate (ex-Content-Type) its depends on type of your API being called